# CSS navigator bar of website for both pc and mobile but not working for mobile size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a navigator bar of website for everysize i.e for both pc and mobile. Here i have already written my code and its working also but when click my dropdownIcon to see my list in mobile screen size its not showing in the format i described but in default format without any action as shown in image.[

```css
/************ Default *************************/
nav,
header,
fotter{
    display:block;
}    
    body{
        line-height:1;
        margin:0;
    }    
/**************** nav bar *********************/


nav{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
nav ul{
    background-color:#eee;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul.topnav li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}
ul.topnav li a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#666;
    padding:14px;
    font-size: 20px;
    min-height: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover{
    background-color: #0080ff;
    color:white;
}

ul.topnav li.topnav-right{
    float:right;
}

ul.topnav li.dropdownIcon{
    float:right;
    display:none;
}

/*************** mobile ************************/
@media screen and (max-width:680px){
    ul.topnav li:not(:nth-child(1)){
        display:none;
    }
    ul.topnav li.dropdownIcon{
        display:block;
    }

    ul.topnav.responsive li.dropdownIcon{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive{
        position:relative;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li{
        display: inline;
        float: none;
    }
    ul.topnav.responsive li a{
        display:block;
        text-align: left;
        
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My CSS Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="topnav" id="dropdownClick">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#signup">Sign up</a></li>
                <li class="topnav-right"><a href="#signin">Sign In</a></li>
                <li class="dropdownIcon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="dropdownMenu()">&#9776;</a></li> 
                
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        
        
        <script>
            function dropdownMenu(){
                var x = document.getElementById("dropdownClick");
                if(x.className=="topnav"){
                    x.className+="responsive";
                }else{
                    x.className="topnav";
                }
                
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you are going to append a class as a string using `x.className+=` then you need to add a space `x.className+=' responsive'` or try `x.classList.add("responsive");`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this row:

```
x.className += "responsive";
```

When you add the class after click on the menu button on mobile,
the class looks like this: `topnavresponsive`,
but it should be: `topnav responsive`,

so you have to change the above row to:

```
x.className += " responsive";
```

Just add space.